# Calling JComboBox#addItem() in a while(resultSet.next()) loop ends up with only 1 item

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

this is the code thats giving me problems.

```
try{
ResultSet rs = Main.dbase.search("select * from myTable");
//rs.next()
while(rs.next())
{
 cmb.addItem(rs.getString(1).trim());
}
rs.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {System.out.println(ex);}
```

here dbase is an object executing Statement.executeQuery, and cmb is JComboBox.

the problem is that even though the table has 10 rows, i get only single row in cmb.
if I don't comment out the first *rs.next()*, i get the 2nd row in cmb.

i tried to track the value of *rs.next()* and found that after *while(rs.next())* it gives out false, always.

My target is to get all the 10 values in cmb.
as fas as i have researched, this code should add all values to cmb, but only a single value is being added.
if before entering the loop i call *rs.next()*, then the next value adds to the cmb.

Comment: How many times does the `while` loop loop? Put a debug breakpoint or a poor man's `System.out.println()` to figure that out.

Comment: what happens if you comment out the cmb.addItem line - does it still only run the while loop once?

Comment: Could you also show us the code that creates the combo box?

Comment: @BalusC and @Ord: whoa! the loop loops the same time as the number of rows if I comment out the addItem line! seems its where the prob lies!

@jfpoilpret:
    cmb = new JComboBox();
    cmb.setBounds(10, 10, 170, 20);
    cmb.addActionListener(this);
    add(cmb);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention if any exception was caught by your `catch` block.

What I see could prevent the loop from going further than the first row, would be that the next row has a `NULL` first column.

Indeed, if there is a `NULL` in the 1st column of any of the rows returned by `"select * from myTable"`, then `rs.getString(1).trim()`will throw a `NullPointerException` that will interrupt the loop.

You can avoid that by writing:

```
try {
    ResultSet rs = Main.dbase.search("select * from myTable"); 
    while(rs.next()) {
        String result = rs.getString(1);
        if (result != null) {
            result = result.trim();
        }
        cmb.addItem(result);
    } 
    rs.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
}
```

In addition, I would improve the whole snippet in order to:

- ensure `rs` is closed even if an exception occurs
- ensure we see the full stack trace of any exception
- ensure that `cmb` is updated exclusively from the EDT (Swing EDT rule)
- avoid too many calls to the EDT by aggregating all `addItems` altogether

Then here is what you would have:

```
ResultSet rs = null; 
try {
    final List<String> allItems = new ArrayList>String>();
    rs = Main.dbase.search("select * from myTable"); 
    while(rs.next()) {
        String result = rs.getString(1);
        if (result != null) {
            result = result.trim();
        }
        allItems.add(result);
    }
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Overrive public run() {
            for (String item: allItems) {
                cmb.addItem(item);
            }
        }
    });
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStacktrace();
} finally {
    if (rs != null) {
        try {
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, some parts can still be improved further, for instance I would probably write a helper method to close a `ResultSet` if it's not `null`, because this code is likely to be reused in many places.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ResultSet` is actually populating correctly, then your problem is with Swing. That is, Swing is not thread-safe. When adding items to the `JComboBox`, it is crucial that you do so in the Event Dispatch Thread, or `EDT`. In order to do this, use the [`SwingUtilities`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html) utility class to post a `Runnable` task on the `EventQueue` to be executed in the `EDT`. For instance,

```
while(rs.next()){
    if(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()){
        cmb.addItem(rs.getString(1).trim());
    }
    else{
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run(){
                cmb.addItem(rs.getString(1).trim());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Regardless of what actually ends up being the problem, please heed this advice.

Comment: it is likely his ResultSet is not populated correctly. he says that rs.next() always returns false. if this is the case then check out your main.db.search() method . this method is probably not returning Strings? it means the first result is a String but the remaining results are not *Strings*. or maybe your query method is not implemented well. post the code in your db.search() so we can help you more.

Comment: I tried your code but still only one item is added. And in your code the else part is not getting executed. I guess you are correct, the problem lies in the addItem line.

Comment: @othman: heres the code
`public ResultSet search(String q){
     try{ return(st.executeQuery(q));}
    catch(Exception e){return null;}`

I think ResultSet is getting populated correctly.

Comment: @max_force, when I first posted this answer, I neglected to include the `run()` method. the updated code I provided in the `else` part should execute now.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but still no luck, mate!

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct structure for what you are doing, so the problem probably lies elsewhere. `SELECT *` is not a good idea in a situation like this, and `SELECT *` combined with `rs.getString(1)` makes it impossible for us to second-guess what is being added to the combo box. I'm going to guess that the first column isn't what you think it is. At the least, use `rs.getString("column_name_I_want")`.

By the way, are you sure you want `search` and not some sort of `execute`?

Comment: well i could do that, but what difference would it make?
My table has only one column ;).
refer my comment to othman for the search method.